# Deleting local instance of class with connected events

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Suppose I have a class with event:

```
    class MyClass 
    {
        public delegate void MyDelegate();
        public event MyDelegate MyEvent;
        public MyClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass created");
        }
        ~MyClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass removed");
        }
        public void MyFunction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass.MyFunction()");
            if (MyEvent != null)
                MyEvent();
        }
    }
```

Assume that `MyFunction` is some asynchronous action so I need an event to know it has finished. Sometimes I need the functionality of the class so I create instance of the class, run that and get a result. After that I expect the instance will be destroyed.

Now I instance this class and connect its event to anonymous functions. To test the functionality I've create a function:

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        MyClass test = new MyClass();
        test.MyEvent += delegate() { Console.WriteLine("MyEvent fired"); };
        test.MyFunction();
    }
```

and so run it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test 1");
        Test();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------\ntest 2");
        Test();
    }
```

The output is:

```
test 1
MyClass created
MyClass.MyFunction()
MyEvent fired
----------------
test 2
MyClass created
MyClass.MyFunction()
MyEvent fired
MyClass removed
MyClass removed
```

Unfortunately, `MyClass` instance is deleted only after the application finished. How can I delete the class (or notify GC to delete that) after using?

Comment: You don't control the garbage collector - let it do its job. Just make sure that the object isn't *referenced* when you're done with it and it will go away when there's memory pressure.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: In your sample? It's eligible for collection as soon as `MyFunction` ends. There's nothing more explicit you can do. What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: I try to avoid memory overhead. If I run `Test` 100 times so will be unusual 100 MyClass objects in memory until the program ends

Comment: What makes you think it's overhead? If you want manual memory control, C# isn't the language for you (sure, you can use unsafe code, but why use C# if you want to write 100% unsafe code?). The garbage collector runs when there's memory pressure. If there's no memory pressure, the objects can survive indefinitely. There's nothing wrong with that.